# Is there an option to hide migrated (or even on hold) questions?

Tags: feature-request

It would make sense, especially for MO, to have an option to hide migrated and on hold questions in the user preferences. Is there a way to do this already? If not I think this would make a nice feature.

I suspect this will not become an official feature but I am sure a user script could be written.

(I am unsure of how migration works so in particular hide questions which are migrated away from MO rather than hiding questions migrated to MO)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

One simple possibility is to use the [search function](https://mathoverflow.net/search) (also usually available on the top right corner of the mathoverflow page) with the query:

```
is:question migrated:no
```

This is equivalent to visiting the url https://mathoverflow.net/search?q=is:question+migrated:no. You can also order these by "active" or "newest" by clicking on the corresponding tab, or by visiting e.g. https://mathoverflow.net/search?tab=active&q=is:question+migrated:no for the "active" tab.

If you want to remove all questions which were closed (including questions on hold) or migrated, you can instead perform a search query for:

```
is:question closed:no
```

For further references on the search function, see the [search tips](https://stackoverflow.com/search). These tips are also available when you use the [search function](https://mathoverflow.net/search) on mathoverflow by clicking "Advanced Search Tips" on the right.

Comment: This answer (an additoinal sentence paraphrasing the question) could make a nice addition to this list http://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/389/what-are-tips-and-tricks-to-use-mo-more-effectively

Comment: @quid: As you suggested, I added a slightly modified version of this answer at the thread you linked to.