# When we close questions and suggest MSE, should we link to their How to Ask?

Tags: feature-request, math-stackexchange, close-reasons, asking-questions

When we close questions by saying

> MathOverflow is for mathematicians to ask each other questions about their research. See [Math.StackExchange](http://math.stackexchange.com/) to ask general questions in mathematics.

...should the link go to the Math StackExchange [How to Ask](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) page?

Many questions which get closed with that response are not good questions for Math StackExchange, because the question does not show what the poster has tried or whether they've looked for answers. Putting in the "How to Ask" link would show that even if the question has the right topic for Math StackExchange, the site has other standards for what questions are worth answering.

Comment: This is probably better than my idea, which is that you shouldn't choose the "See Math.StackExchange" reason when you vote to close, unless you have spent enough time on that website to know about their standards.

Comment: Perhaps it's worth mentioning that *every* user on Mathematics is shown [How to Ask](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/ask/advice) page when asking *their first question.* But showing this information more often - also to users coming from MO - might be useful. (Here is the [discussion on Mathematics Meta](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/21512/show-how-to-ask-advice-before-a-new-user-asks-a-question) where this was introduced. A similar feature was discussed also [here on MO](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/q/3386).)