# Possible additional option for "See Math.Stackexchange" close vote

Tags: feature-request, math-stackexchange, close-reasons, flagging

Some of the most common close votes are for people who have posted homework questions, to which the usual appropriate response (to my understanding) is to flag as off-topic with the message "MathOverflow is for mathematicians to ask each other questions about their research. See Math.StackExchange to ask general questions in mathematics." However, many of those questions fail to show any work, which leads to the question being inappropriate there as asked. This often leads to comments that are all approximately the same: "This is not appropriate here; you may have better luck on m.se. There, you will have to show your work."

It may be useful to include an option (possibly on selection of the quoted option, possibly on deletion, etc.) to add something like "This looks like an assigned problem; you will have to show your work so far and explain where you are getting stuck" or something similar.

Comment: I will add that Michael Albanese suggested collecting some comments about moving to [math.se] in this question: [Comment template for questions more appropriate for MSE](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/q/971). It is also worth mentioning is that what matters on Math.SE is [providing context](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/9960#9960) to the question. One way is to show your own work, but there are other things which count as context, too.

Comment: And perhaps it's worth mentioning that "[How to ask a good question.](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) post" on [math.meta.se] is also linked here: [My question was closed on MO because it is not research level. Where should I ask instead?](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/q/3760) This post is linked [in the help center](https://mathoverflow.net/help/on-topic) on MO.

Comment: Some older posts on this meta which seem related to your suggestion: [When we close questions and suggest MSE, should we link to their How to Ask?](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/q/4168) and [Are we making it too tempting/easy to send inappropriate posts to MSE?](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/q/4217)

Comment: @MartinSleziak Apparently I am not good at searching meta.MO; I'm happy to count this as a duplicate of the Comment template question.