# Make edit history more accessible

Tags: feature-request, user-interface, design, revision-history

Once a post has been edited once, there is a direct link to the revision history of the post that is visible to everyone as in this example:

[image: Edit link sample]

However, when a post has not been edited, this link is not directly accessible. The revision history still exists: one has to manually change

`http://mathoverflow.net/questions/123456789/...`

to

`http://mathoverflow.net/posts/123456789/revisions`

to access it.

Admittedly, there is little point in doing this when the post hasn't been edited. However, for the purpose of transparency, it would be useful to have access to the post history even if there is nothing to see. In fact, for the purpose of academic citations, which is of great interest to MathOverflow, it would be best to have access to direct links to specific versions of a post.

Moreover, non-edit actions such as open/close and delete/undelete history cannot be seen without doing a manual url change. This is in opposition to the moderation transparency that MathOverflow seeks to have.

*Remark (added on Oct 4, 2015):* This feature request is still pending.

Comment: There are GM scripts for that.

Comment: Kaveh mentions [such a script](http://stackapps.com/questions/2138/se-modifications-username-autocomplete-in-comments-inline-revision-source-a) on a [vaguely  related post](http://meta.mathoverflow.net/a/391/9072) That being said I think that mainly to have this change, which I fully support, would be relevant for thos that do not know it is possible at all so that they know (rather than as a convenience for those that do know)

Comment: Related to this perhaps one could also think about *displaying* the info that the center link leads to revision history (rather than just having it as a tooltip). Like 'see all revisions (last changed [timestamp])' instead of 'edited [timestanmp]'

Comment: By the way, while we're at it, we might as well ask for the timeline link to be made accessible.

Comment: @AsafKaragila The timeline is an unsupported feature, and it looks rather confusing to anyone not familiar with the details of this feature. I  doubt it will be available publicly anytime soon. Though I'd really like a better timeline feature accessible to non-mods, the mod-only timeline is already pretty good (though it has a different purpose than the timeline you mentioned).

Comment: I'm going to bring this up on our feature call this week. So what you're basically saying is whenever there's no edits, just have a link that says 'history' instead?

Comment: Also, note, as a moderator you can get a _very_ detailed history by clicking on mod -> timeline on any post (I do realize that this is about the public one, I just wanted to make sure you knew it was there as it's quite new)

Comment: @TimPost: Thanks! Yes, a history/revisions link that is always accessible even if a post hasn't been edited. We would be happy to discuss implementation details.

Comment: Related posts on [meta.se]: [Show link to revision history when there are revisions but no edits](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/168765) and [Add a link to /revisions from the timeline](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/347405).

Comment: Regarding "non-edit actions such as open/close and delete/undelete history", these can now be seen by navigating to the timeline of the post, by clicking on the clock icon below the vote buttons.