# Is there a way to learn when MO leads to actual results?

Tags: support, citations

Where can I find information about MO activity which led to progress in somebody's research? E.g. is there an efficient way to cite MO contribution in a paper in such a way that it will be easily detected here?

Comment: I'm pretty sure it leads to results more often than is cited in these "success stories"!

Comment: @ToddTrimble I tend to agree. Perhaps there should be a more low profile way to selfreport such things. I mean even if one wanted, one could hesitate to (self-)include ones paper/question/answer in an MO "Best of."

Comment: @quid Yes, there have been a few cases when some MO answers of mine have been used by others, but it seems a little grandiose to self-promote these as "success stories". I expect this is the case with many users.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is a thread on meta dedicated mainly to tracking MO's impact on (published) research, see [Best of MathOverflow, or papers inspired by MathOverflow](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/617/best-of-mathoverflow) which continued http://mathoverflow.tqft.net/discussion/64/where-to-keep-track-of-mathoverflow-success-stories/ (on the old meta board).

I do not know of a way (other than posting it there) that actually ensures that it will be noticed here. However, using the recommended form for citing, which one should do anyway, will presumably increase the chances it is picked up whenever somebody searches for mention of MO in the literature.

To get this recommended form (also in bibtex and amsrefs format), just click 'share' below a post and then 'cite'.

You might also be interested in [Improving citations of MathOverflow posts](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/1462/improving-citations-of-mathoverflow-posts) that discusses ways to improve the ways in which MO is or can be cited.

Comment: Thank you! These are very interesting links.

Sooner or later one has to invent some mechanism to make detectability of the interaction between MO and the traditional research more systematic...

Comment: @მამუკაჯიბლაძე: You can find references to MO on the arxiv through this search - http://search.arxiv.org:8081/?query=%22math+overflow%22+OR+mathoverflow&in=grp_math

Comment: @FrançoisG.Dorais Thank you, I've found something like this when following one of the above links and discovered several interesting publications :)