# Why is my question apparently not research-level?

Tags: discussion, asking-questions

I just posted [this question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/179209/need-help-solving-the-divisibility-condition-ab2-mid-2b36ab2-1) a few hours ago, and it's already had two votes to close for being off-topic (*i.e.*, not of "research-level mathematics"). Considering it's ultimately a question about elliptic curves, it has been unanswered in an MSE thread for almost a year, and I'm working on this to include in a paper for submission to number theory journals, I'm a little confused as to how it's not "research-level".

Comment: I think the reason for the close votes is likely rather the *formulation* of the question than the question as such. -- In particular, I think it is not good style to ask people to fill in the gaps in a draft of a proof, or to let people find errors in one's argumentation. I would just pose this as a terse 2-line question, followed by a few lines of explanation particularly mentioning the (11364,46061) example.

Comment: You might explain how it's ultimately a question about elliptic curves or at any rate explain why it's deeper than elementary number theory. There are *so many* questions that get posted inappropriately at MO that it's easy to understand why a problem which looks at first glance to be elementary but is deep in disguise may be closed on the basis of quick impressions.

Comment: @StefanKohl: Interesting. Thanks for that. I was under the impression that _not_ showing that I've done work on the problem would put me in worse stead.

Comment: @ToddTrimble: Thanks. Should I remove all of the existing explanation (as suggested by Stefan Kohl), or add this new information?

Comment: I'm not sure how to pose the question in any way that satisfies the implied requirements. In particular, to Stefan Kohl's point, what would a "terse 2-line question" look like in this case?

Comment: I'm guessing the "terse 2-line question" could just be the bit before you embark on the partial proof. (I see Stefan's point: the proposed line of attack might after all be a dead end, and trying to follow the close reasoning might be distracting to some readers. It might work better as an addendum, headed by a "FWIW".) OTOH: the question also looks somewhat unmotivated. If you have an interesting number-theoretic context that you could explain (possibly involving integral points on elliptic curves or something else that is relevant), that might help garner interest in your question.

Comment: I've done my best to incorporate your suggestions. Thank you.

Comment: @ToddTrimble: Thanks for the help. And I don't at all mind your edit on my original post! That being said… It would seem to me that a question like “Is this conjecture correct?” [potentially with much less work shown] is __less__ 'research-level' than what I originally had. Am I wrong?

Comment: Potentially, maybe, but I think in the present case it's offset by the work you've evidently put into this. I wouldn't have performed the edit but for the fact that MO can be a little peculiar; an imperative verb like "Consider..." without an accompanying question has been known to rub people the wrong way, which I wanted to avoid. In any case, it looks as though this question will now stay open. :-)

Comment: There was no reason to close the question to begin with, but now, in view of the answers, it is clear that closing it would have been a big loss for MO.

Comment: I continue to believe that if this page of excellent advice http://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/882/how-to-write-a-good-mathoverflow-question were made more accessible on the main site, such situations would be less likely to occur.