# Limiting the length of questions?

Tags: discussion, asking-questions

Many questions on MO are not formulated as concisely as they could be. I would propose a limit of characters (to be discussed, say 500 characters), and you can "buy" more space by sacrificing some of your reputation (say, 500 more characters for -20 reputation).

Silly proposition? (Probably yes, but not having thought about it a great deal, it makes sense to me.)

Comment: Odd proposition ... . In the spirit of your question -- why not rather limiting the *number* of questions a user can ask in relation to the number of well-received answers they have given? -- E.g. #questions - #answers $\leq 250$ or so?

Comment: If an average word is 5 characters, and a picture is worth 1000 words, then the 500 character limit would permit only one-tenth of a picture per question. How would Joseph O'Rourke cope?

Comment: LOL ok, I see it was a very bad idea of mine... Sorry for the traffic jam, folks

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I'm sorry, but this idea seems completely wrong to me. Not just because 500 characters (less than a comment box) is too parsimonious, but because most questions could actually stand *more* in the way of setting context, motivation, descriptions of what the OP has tried, rejected, and so on.

There are some users who frequently add a lot of padding to their posts; of course this is not to be encouraged. Usually conciseness is a virtue. But the point is that users should do whatever they can, within limits of reason, to smooth the way for others to provide meaningful help.

Comment: In connection to this it might be worth mentioning that *providing background and motivation* is explicitly mentioned in the FAQ post [How to write a good MathOverflow question?](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/q/882) (And massively reducing number of characters would certainly make this much difficult.)